# solving for exponent of quadratic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem:

$$(2^x - 4) \cdot (2^x - 2) = 0$$

I really have no idea how to introduce logarithms to this to solve it...

It expands to:

$$2^{2x} - 2^{x + 1} - 2^{x+2}  + 8 = 0$$

How do I turn that into logarithms?

Comment: What if you set 'each' quantity (parens) equal to zero?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Instead of expanding, use the fact that $$ab = 0 \iff a = 0 \text{ or } b = 0$$ That is, consider separately

$$2^x - 4 = 0$$

and $$2^x - 2 = 0$$

Comment: Oh wow, thanks!